# Unable to import tensorflow, error for importing pywrap_tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use Keras Sequential, however, my jupyter notebook is flooded with error as it's not able to import tensorflow in the backend (i think). Later I found that, its not with Keras, but I am not able to do 'import tensorflow as tf' as well.

Any suggestions, please?
I am using python 3.5.6
tensorflow 1.12

I did, pip install tensorflow for installation.

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in swig_import_helper()
     17         try:
---> 18             fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
     19         except ImportError:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in find_module(name, path)
    295     else:
--> 296         raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
    297

ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py in 
     53     # use `dlopen()` for dynamic loading.
---> 54     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     55 except ImportError:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in swig_import_helper()
     19         except ImportError:
---> 20             import _pywrap_tensorflow
     21             return _pywrap_tensorflow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py in 
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py in 
     58 please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
     59 from there.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 60   raise ImportError(msg)
     61 
     62 # Protocol buffers

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ritesh.kankonkar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
  File "C:\Users\ritesh.kankonkar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ritesh.kankonkar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\ritesh.kankonkar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\ritesh.kankonkar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am answering my own question since the error seems to have multiple causes.
I am not sure what was the cause, however, after downgrading python to 3.5 and installing tensorflow with pip (pip install tensorflow), resolved the issue.

Note: I uninstalled everything before installing Anaconda again.

Comment: I resolved the same issue thanks to this tuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRaRi6f5Qcs (installing tensorflow for sse)